# Pygame image rectangle collides with everything except for the left wall

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Trying to make a start screen for my game for high school class. The image is supposed to move around the screen colliding with each wall and moving in the next direction. For some reason the image will not collide with the left wall and I can't figure out why.

```
class StartScreen:
    def __init__(self):
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        self.fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 30) #
        self.textTitle = self.fontTitle.render("Legend Of Zelda: ", True, WHITE) 
        self.textRect = self.textTitle.get_rect(center=(displayWidth / 2, 50)) 
        self.moveImage = pygame.image.load("images/link_down1.png")
        self.moveImageRect = self.moveImage.get_rect()
        self.dx = 3
        self.dy = 0
        self.moveImageRect.x = 1
        self.moveImageRect.y = 11
    def update(self):
        if self.moveImageRect.right >= displayWidth:
            self.dy = 3
            self.dx = 0
        if self.moveImageRect.left <= 0:
            self.dy = -1
            self.dx = 0
        if self.moveImageRect.top <= 0:
            self.dy = 0
            self.dx = -3
        elif self.moveImageRect.bottom >= displayHeight:
            self.dx = -3
            self.dy = 0
        self.moveImageRect.move_ip(self.dx, self.dy)

    def draw(self, surf):
        screen.blit(backgroundImage, (backgroundRect)) 
        screen.blit(self.textTitle, self.textRect) 
        screen.blit(backgroundImage, (backgroundRect)) 
        screen.blit(self.moveImage, self.moveImageRect)
```

Comment: Well the only difference is that for the left, `self.dy = -1` instead of 3. you also change `dy` for up, left and right but change `dx` for down. Are you trying to go for the bouncing dvd player effect?

Comment: no trying to move it clockwise around the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
if self.moveImageRect.right > 500:
    dy = 1
    dx = 0
    self.moveImageRect.right = 500
elif self.moveImageRect.bottom > 500:
    dy = 0
    dx = -1
    self.moveImageRect.bottom = 500
elif self.moveImageRect.left < 0:
    dy = -1
    dx = 0
    self.moveImageRect.left = 0
elif self.moveImageRect.top < 0:
    dy = 0
    dx = 1
    self.moveImageRect.top = 0
```

This worked for me, only checking if the image moves off the screen then moving it back on the screen makes sure that its not colliding with a wall when its not.